# Performance issue Sqlite in a tomcat server

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, tomcat, query-performance

I'm using a Tomcat 6 with the Xerial sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar driver. SQLite3 has the version 3.6.20.

If the server is under load, processing of a request needs unbelievable long. Normally one request needs less than 100 ms. Under load it rises up to 3 seconds.

Long time I had no idea what's going on. Since yesterday I believe that Sqlite blocks the read access. I could see that a lot of threads are blocking by reading the ResultSet.

```
"http-8080-34" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ffca0049800 nid=0x78b2 waiting for monitor entry     [0x00007ffcbc5e0000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.column_text(Native Method)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000f8836508> (a org.sqlite.NativeDB)
    at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:562)
    at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:569)
```

First I tried an in-memory database, then shared cache. Both solution had the problem that the connection need CREATE open flag to copy the tables from hard disk into memory.

Since yesterday I want only read access from hard disk, but I couldn't see a change of the described result. It looks for me serialized.

I'm using one connection which is created in the Servlet init method. With the NOMUTEX flag I was thinking I can activate mutli-threading during runtime.

```
        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
        config.setReadOnly(true);
        config.setSharedCache(true);
        config.setReadUncommited(true);
        config.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.NOMUTEX);
        connection = config.createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        config.apply(connection);
```

If I didn't have a big misunderstanding I'm coming to the result that I can't use Sqlite in an multi-threaded environment like a Tomcat server which uses 200 maxThreads by default.

During my research work I was using sqlite4java as well and here a queue was used. With this driver I could be really sure that the SELECT request where handled sequentially.

Here the result how sqlite is compiled:

```
java -jar sqlite4java.jar 
sqlite4java 282
SQLite 3.7.10
Compile-time options: ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA ENABLE_FTS3 ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT ENABLE_RTREE OMIT_DEPRECATED TEMP_STORE=1 THREADSAFE=1
```

Is my assumption correct that I can't read data multi-threaded from the db? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQLite version is a few years out of date, but this problem is unlikely to be solved by a better query optimizer, or by enabling [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

SQLite is designed for embedded applications.
It uses a single database-wide lock; while this works correctly for concurrent accesses, it is optimized to speed up nonconcurrent program.

Using SQLite just [is not appropriate for high-volume web sites](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).
Use some DB that is designed to be scalable.